# How to enable Diagnostic Tools for MVC application

Tags: diagnostics

I had already available the diagnostic tools. Then, I deactivated the tools via
Options-->Debugging->Diagnostic tools while debugging (checkbox unchecked).

Now, I checked this setting and restarted VS2015. The diagnostic tools are not running anymore in parallel to the debugging session in a MVC application like before.

Does anyone know what to do?

Yours
Stephan

Comment: Solution found: with Ctrl-Alt-F2 , the diagnostic tools window is back. You can also use menu Debugging->Display Diagnostic Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: with Ctrl-Alt-F2 , the diagnostic tools window is back. You can also use menu Debugging->Display Diagnostic Tools.